# How to add new label in window?

Tags: python, button, pyqt

I have a window. There is a button. When the user clicks on this button, in the window must disappear button and appear new label and new button. 
Do you understand?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
def starting():
    quest1 = QtGui.QWidget()
    quest1.setWindowTitle('New')
    quest1.resize(900, 600)
    quest1.show()
    quest1.exec()


testing = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('Title')
window.resize(900, 600)

MainText = QtGui.QLabel('<p align="center"; style="font-size: xx-large">Text</p>')
Mainbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

# buttons
start = QtGui.QPushButton('Start')
quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit')
start.setFixedSize(70, 40)
quit.setFixedSize(70, 40)

buttons = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
buttons.addWidget(start)
buttons.addWidget(quit)
# /buttons


Mainbox.addWidget(MainText)
Mainbox.addLayout(buttons)

window.setLayout(Mainbox)

QtCore.QObject.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))
QtCore.QObject.connect(start, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), starting)

window.show()
sys.exit(testing.exec_())
```

I think, I do wrong, is not required to make new window, but I don`t know what I must doing.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve. What does the existing window look like? What *specific* widgets do you need to add/remove/change? The current code you've posted has no relevance to the questions you are asking.

Comment: I edited. Maybe it is more clearer.

Comment: You need to post the actual code you have already, and say which parts you are having difficulty with. You should not expect people to write all the code for you.

Comment: OK, I will post my actual code. But, I don`t need all code, I want to understand what algorithm I must use.

Comment: Eureka!!! I learned how to add a new button (or label). Code like this: def starting():
    buttonnew = QtGui.QPushButton('New buton')
    Mainbox.addWidget(buttonnew)

Comment: But what I must doing if I want to delete some elements?

Comment: You can remove a widget from a layout using [`removeWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#removeWidget), and destroy the widget with [`deleteLater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater). I think you should also consider creating a class for the main window and make all the child widgets attributes of that class. That way you can reference everything with `self`, rather than using global variables.

Comment: But it doesn`t work! For example: Mainbox.removeWidget()

Answer (score 2):

Qt UIs are built from widgets. Many widgets can have children. If you add/remove children, the UI will update accordingly.

The problem with the code above is that you don't add the new widget to a parent. So what happens is: You create the widget, you force it to appear, the function ends, the local variables (`newwindow`) end up on the trash and Python cleans the trash -> the widget is deleted again.

For the window to stay, you need to add it to some parent widget (probably the window). If you want to replace existing widgets, you need to remove them yourself.